# jQuery validator with Rails form still submitting on Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, jquery-validate

I have a Rails signup form that I'm using [jQuery validator](https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails) to validate. It works perfectly on localhost, but when run on Heroku it seems to run the validation but immediately also submit the form, leading to a page reload and Rails model errors showing. I confirmed this by not entering any information at all into fields, hitting submit, and jQuery errors appear - but immediately the page begins reloading (submitting).

Adding `debug: true` to the `validate()` call which is supposed to prevent form submission and simply show errors (which, again, works on localhost) still leads to the form submitting on Heroku.

I have spent hours console logging, commenting bit by bit, without result. Any help or ideas appreciated!

**Edit:** Adding more code-specific code thanks to @Sparky pointing out the necessity:

I am using the [jQuery validate gem](https://github.com/danryan/jquery-validation-rails) and [jQuery payment gem](https://github.com/vladchi/jquery-payment-rails). I have a JS file in `app/assets/javascripts` that I'm using specific to this page which has the requires:

```
//= require jquery.payment
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
```

And the content:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.form-signup').validate();
});
```

My application.js has:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require log
//= require_self
```

The signup page is a HAML devise form:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:class => 'form form-signup control-group' }) do |f|
 = f.input :first_name, :autofocus => true, :placeholder => "First name", :label => false
 = f.input :last_name, :placeholder => "Last name", :label => false
 = f.input :email, :placeholder => "Email", :label => false, :required => true
 = f.input :password, :placeholder => "Password", :label => false, :input_html => { minlength: 6 }, :required => true
 = f.submit "Sign Up Now", :class => 'btn btn-success', :id => "signup-button"
```

No errors are logged to console.

This works locally, but on Heroku the jQuery validations show yet it still submits the form.

Comment: Take a look at the console in your browser, are there any errors on console?

Comment: No, there aren't any errors in console.

Comment: You've shown us nothing... no code, no markup, not even the error messages.

Comment: @Sparky there are no error messages. The code is irrelevant - this happens on a basic Rails form, performing the minimal amount to get jQuery validate to work: `$('.form').validate();`. I find it likely something to do with Heroku or how it's deployed through the asset pipeline or something, considering it works perfectly on local setup. Re-iterating that jQuery validate *does* do its job, however for some reason the form is also instantly submitted leading to AR validations.

Comment: What you describe is impossible... that's why I'm asking to see the code.  If it's something _"deployed through the asset pipeline or something"_, then show the **relevant code as seen by the browser**.  Besides, without code, [this is off-topic as per #2](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic):  _"Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — **and include valid code to reproduce it — in the question itself**. See [SSCCE.org](http://SSCCE.org) for guidance."_

Answer (score 0):

Jquery validation execute after the JQuery requirements.

app/assets/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.validate
//= require jquery.validate.additional-methods
//= require_tree .

and 

We need to include like this

= javascript_include_tag "application", "rails.validations"
```

Comment: The OP has shown us nothing, so your answer is based on what?

Comment: My suggestion, on Heroku production it compile all js file into aplication.js. we require some js files in the  application.js, these are should be in order otherwise it get conflicted. It's best to put that js into assets>javascript folder manually.